# After updating to the new Creators Update my monitor shows strange patterns when coming out of standby

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1709

[image]

My computer is roughly a month old and my monitor is quite old. Recently I installed the Windows 10 Creators Update. When I awake my computer from standby it looks like the above image.

Restarting the PC by cutting power and pressing the start button gets it going again.

I'm not sure whether it's a hardware or software issue. What should I do about it?

Comment: Have you downloaded the current Intel/Nvidia/AMD display drivers?  The drivers supplied through Windows Update, are not typically, the current version of the driver when it comes to display drivers.  Any additional information should be provided by editing your question not submitting a comment.

Comment: @Ramhound : I did run Snappy Driver Installer to update to the latest available drivers.

Comment: Wouldn't trust that program to serve you the current drivers.  Download them directly from Intel/Nvidia/AMD and call it a day